# Vector space of real sequences and its subspace

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having a difficult time with understanding subspaces. I'd appreciate any insight on this question:

Let $R^ \infty$ be the vector space of all real sequences and let $W \subseteq R^ \infty$ be all sequences with only a finite number of nonzero components. Show that $W$ is a subspace of $R^ \infty$

Comment: Just show that it's a vector space ( satisfies the axioms ) and contained in the original space.  Most of the axioms are inherited; you basically just need to check that it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $|v|$ the number of zeros in the sequence $v\in W.$
Then for every sequences $v_1,v_2\in W$ and every $r\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$|v_1-v_2|\leq |v_1|+|v_2| <\infty , \ |r\cdot v_1| = |v_1|<\infty$.
Thus $v_1-v_2\in W$ and $r\cdot v_1\in W$. So, $W$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$.